# GPUs are only detected in conda base environment, not in new one

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

I'm working on Windows Server 2019 and I'm trying to use the GPUs with tensorflow. When I'm in the `base` directory, the GPUs are detected

```
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'), 
PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:1', device_type='GPU')]
```

I created a new environment with conda and installed the same tensorflow version there (2.10.0), but now, the GPUs are not detected anymore.

```
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
[]
```

Any idea what could be the reason? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your base conda environment has tensorflow compiled against CUDA installed. Your new conda environment doesn't. This is why you shouldn't install things in base.

Comment: Thanks! That was also my motivation to create a new environment, but how can I compile TF here against the CUDA installed?

Comment: You don't need to compile it. You need to install the one that's already been compiled against CUDA (like how you installed the one in base).

Comment: I could figure it out, somthing goes wrong when installing via conda, installing via pip helps, as then the correct version seems to be collected

Comment: Are you using `conda install tensorflow-gpu`? If so, older versions did not install the cudatoolkit so you might also try `conda install cudatoolkit`

Comment: No, I used conda install tensorflow, I had in mind that CPU and GPU version are bundled and GPU version does not need to be installed extra, is this correct?